# Preventing CSS grid columns from overflowing using repeat auto-fit with minmax(<fixed-breadth>, 1fr)

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to prevent a column from being larger than the grid width when using `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(<fixed-breadth>, 1fr))`?

I'm hoping for a solution that avoids media queries to make the component more reusable. Each item in the grid should always stay the largest it can be so the `1fr` needs to stay as the second argument.

In the below example, there's a constrained grid and a free grid. The constrained grid has a maximum width limited on it and the columns are larger than the maximum width.

The red background shows column width. The green background shows the grid width.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));

  margin-bottom: 1em;

  padding-top: 1em;
  background-color: green;
}

.item {
  background-color: red;
  border: black solid 1px;
}

.grid.smaller {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
Free grid:
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>        
</div>

Constrained grid:
<div class="grid smaller">
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>        
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it will help.

```css
:root {
  --width: 250px;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(var(--width), 1fr));
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding-top: 1em;
  background-color: green;
}

.item {
  background-color: red;
  border: black solid 1px;
}

.grid.smaller {
  width: 100px;
  --width: 100px;
}
```

```html
Free grid:
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
</div>

Constrained grid:
<div class="grid smaller">
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
  <div class="item">Some content</div>
</div>
```